# CSS Animation not running in Webkit based browsers

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-animations

I want to toggle one image with another and vice-versa continuously with some time delay. This is not working in Webkit browsers such as Chrome and Safari.

Here's what I'm doing:

```css
.bkgd_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.top {
  animation-name: toggle;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes toggle {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="bottom bkgd_img" src="http://www.placehold.it/500/FF0000" />
<img class="top bkgd_img" src="http://www.placehold.it/500/FF9900" />
```

The problem that I'm getting is that the "top" image never becomes transparent, the animation does not happen. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are an Engineer, fix it :DD

Comment: Your example works fine, but it wont work in Chrome, Opera or Safari as these [require the `-webkit` extenstion](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) Add that as well and you're good to go.

Comment: @misterManSam I'm running it in chrome

Comment: As I said, Chrome needs the `-webkit` extension :) [this example works](http://jsbin.com/bujufo/1/edit) in Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox and IE 10 +. The `webkit` prefix is placed above the non prefixed property.

Comment: @Engineer - I should hope so! You can simplify your CSS by using the `animation` property to combine all the properties into one - `-webkit-animation: toggle 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
 animation: toggle 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;`

Comment: @misterManSam got it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Do I need to use browser prefixes for CSS3 Animation in Webkit based browsers?

#### Yes, the `-webkit-` prefix is still required currently.

Take a look at [this reference here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) — Currently Chrome, Safari and Opera require the `-webkit-` prefix in order to support Keyframe Animations.

**A note to future readers** — This will change in the future as browser vendors adapt the native animation properties. Ensure that the non-prefixed animation property is also used *underneath* the webkit prefix.

### Complete Example

**Note:** The non prefixed property should be placed *underneath* the `-webkit-` prefix. This ensures that supporting browsers will use the native CSS property.

The animation properties have been condensed into one: `animation: toggle 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate`

```css
.bkgd_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.top {
  -webkit-animation: toggle 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: toggle 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes toggle {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes toggle {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="bottom bkgd_img" src="http://www.placehold.it/500/FF0000" />
<img class="top bkgd_img" src="http://www.placehold.it/500/FFFF00" />
```

Answer (score 1):

tested your code in Firefox 32 and IE10 and Chrome 36. It seems to work fine with IE and Mozilla. But does not work well with chrome. Chrome has different CSS notations, it is not able to read them, kindly use following code for chrome. You can retain your previous code for other browsers

```
    .top {
        -webkit-animation-name:toggle;
        animation-name: toggle;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
        -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes toggle {
        0% {
            opacity:1;
        }
        45% {
            opacity:1;
        }
        55% {
            opacity:0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity:0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed vendor specific css property.

```
-webkit-animation: toggle 5s infinite; 

@-webkit-keyframes toggle {}
```

Refer the working code.
http://codepen.io/bhuvana/pen/dPYzdZ

Comment: Is it still a requirement to include all 4 vendor specific prefixes:  
  
@-webkit-keyframes  
@-moz-keyframes  
@-o-keyframes  
@keyframes  
  
?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JQuery with a simple way of doing this. There are other ways of doing it example: `toggle()`

HTML:

```
<img class="bottom bkgd_img" src="xyz.jpg" id="img-change" />
```

JQuery:

```
$('#img-change').on({
'click': function () {
    var originalsrc = $(this).attr('src');
    var src = '';
    if (originalsrc == 'xyz.jpg') src = 'abc.jpg';
    if (originalsrc == 'abc.jpg') src = 'xyz.jpg';
    $(this).attr('src', src);
}
```

});

Note: I didn't try it, but it probably works.

Comment: I was looking for a solution with only CSS itself

Answer (score 0):

You have to use vendor specific code, you can check it in below code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .bkgd_img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;

}
.top {
    -webkit-animation: 5s 'toggle' infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: 5s 'toggle' infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: 5s 'toggle' infinite alternate;
    animation: 5s 'toggle' infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes 'toggle' {
   0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    45% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    55% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}@-webkit-keyframes 'toggle' {
   0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    45% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    55% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}@-moz-keyframes 'toggle' {
   0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    45% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    55% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}@-o-keyframes 'toggle' {
   0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    45% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    55% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="bottom bkgd_img" src="xyz.jpg" />
    <img class="top bkgd_img" src="abc.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```